# 200kB file to search for 8! (40320 permutations) in Python or IDA

Tags: python, ida, hexdump

I am working on disassembling a firmware (Siemens C165 processor - https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-C165-DS-v02_00-en%5B8%5D.pdf?fileId=db3a304412b407950112b43a49a66fd7) in IDA.

I have the firmware, so I can also read it via Python.

I need to find a string being permutation of

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 (0-7)
```

Wrote this simple program:

```
from itertools import permutations 
l = list(permutations(range(0,8))) 
print(len(l))

with open("firm.ori", 'rb') as f:
    s = f.read()
for i in l:
    hexstr = '\\x'.join('{:02x}'.format(x) for x in i)
    hexstrfinal = "\\0x" + hexstr
    #print hexstrfinal
    if(s.find(b'hexstrfinal')>0):
        print "found"
```

However, it does not find anything

I thought the sequence will be next to each other, but maybe not.

Want to just be sure that the program is correct.

Well actually, 0-7 should be nibbles, so does it mean I need to search for, for example as a one combination:

```
0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67
```

Above is bytes.

Can somebody confirm this and advise how to search for this?

**Update 1:**

Tried 2nd variant

```
from itertools import permutations 
l = list(permutations(range(0,8))) 
print(len(l))

with open("firm.ori", 'rb') as f:
  s = f.read()
for item in l:
  str1 = ''.join(str(e) for e in item)
  n = 2
  out = [str1[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(str1), n)]

  hexstr = '\\x'.join(e for e in out)
  hexstrfinal  = "\\x" + hexstr 
  #print hexstrfinal
  if(s.find(b'hexstrfinal')>0):
    print "found"
```

But also no hits ...

Any ideas what I do wrong?

Comment: You may want to look at https://chortle.ccsu.edu/AssemblyTutorial/Chapter-15/ass15_3.html

Comment: Thanks. You mean the endianess? I guess it would hit the right combination in all these attempts, no? Or you mean something else. BTW I updated with second snippet Update 2: It does the permutation on nibbles.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to search for. Every permutation will have seven items. are you saying that for **each** permutation, you want to take the items two at a time and construct a seven item sequence like this? `(7, 6, 4, 1, 3, 5, 0, 2) ->> bytes([76,64,41,13,35,2]) --> b'L@)\r#\x02'`? Then search the file for that sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few misunderstandings in your code, and a major inefficiency. Let's start with the misunderstandings.

Since `firm.ori` is opened in binary mode (`rb`), the result of `s = f.read()` is a `bytes` object. Despite having similar methods to a string, this is not a string! It contains bytes, not characters. When you display it, the `\x...` outputs do not indicate that the `bytes` object containing ASCII backslashes and xes. Instead, each `\x...` is an escape sequence used to represent the hex value of a given byte that does not correspond to an ASCII printable character.

Inside your loop, you deal exclusively with strings: `hexstr = '\\x'.join('{:02x}'.format(x) for x in i)` takes your permutation and formats it to look like the string representation of a `bytes` object. Hopefully you understand from the previous paragraph why this won't work.

`s.find(b'hexstrfinal')` searches for the literal ASCII array `b'hexstrfinal'`, not for the variable named `hexstrfinal`. The latter wouldn't work of course, because `hexstrfinal` has type `str`, not `bytes`. If you were to convert it to `bytes` using a simple `hexstrfinal.encode('ascii')`, you'd get `b'\\x...'`, which is not at all what you want. The proper way would be

```
s.find(hexstrfinal.encode('ascii').decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1'))
```

Hopefully you can see why it is unnecessarily inefficient to convert a string three times to get the `bytes` you want. Any time you start using strings as a crutch to manipulate numbers is a good time to evaluate your approach. That begins our discussion of the inefficiencies in your code.

You are currently attempting to iterate through all the possible permutations of 0-7 rather than looking for the permutations that are actually there. Given that the file is only 200KB in size, it would be unreasonable to expect all or even most permutations to appear in it. Moreover, you are searching the entire file for each possible permutation. For a file size `N` and `K` permutations, your code runs in `O(N * K)` time, while it's possible to do this in a single pass through the file, or `O(N)`. With the appropriate data structures, even a loop written in plain Python will likely run faster than an optimized version of the current code.

The strategy is simple. Iterate through `s`. If the current character and the following seven make up a valid permutation, start a party. Otherwise, keep looking:

```
N = 8
allowed = set(range(N))
for index, b in enumerate(s):
    if b in allowed and set(s[index:index + N]) == allowed:
        print(f'Found sequence {s[index:index + N]} at offset {index}')
```

There are a host of possible optimizations possible here, and you could probably do the whole thing way more efficiently with numpy or scipy.

Things would also get more complicated if you allowed repeats in the sequence. In that case, you'd have to sort the sequences:

```
allowed = sorted(...)
N = len(allowed)
for index, b in enumerate(s):
    if b in allowed and sorted(s[index:index + N]) == allowed:
        print(f'Found sequence {s[index:index + N]} at offset {index}')
```

If you are going to search for nibbles, things get more complicated still. I would drop entirely the check `b in allowed`, and just write a custom check that could be applied at every half-step:

```
N = 8

def build_set(items):
    output = set()
    for b in items:
        output.add(b & 0xF)
        output.add((b >> 4) & 0xF)
    return output

def matches(seq):
    if len(seq) == N // 2:
        return build_set(seq) == allowed
    elif len(seq) == N // 2 + 1:
        check = build_set(seq[1:-1])
        check.add(seq[0] & 0xF)
        check.add((seq[-1] >> 4) & 0xF)
        return check == allowed
    else:
        return False

allowed = set(range())
for index, b in enumerate(s):
    if matches(s[index:index + N // 2]):
        print(f'Found sequence {s[index:index + N // 2]} at offset {index}.0')
     if matches(s[index:index + N // 2 + 1]):
        print(f'Found sequence {s[index:index + N // 2 + 1]]} at offset {index}.5')
```

Here, `build_set` just splits the nibbles into a set. `matches` checks either an array of 8 nibbles aligned on a byte (4 elements), or an array of 8 nibbles offset by half a byte (5 elements). Both cases are reported independently.

Comment: Thanks! Great answer. It actually seem to be working :) To give you some background, I am trying to find cryptographic pbox an sbox. pbox is 8 elements and sbox 16. So to find the combination for sbox, I just need to change my set to {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15} ? .... the problem is I tried that and it didn't find anything. Anything I missed? I think it should be also 2 nibbles in one byte, like with pbox. Thanks,

Comment: Tried to adjust your code to find 16 elements permutations, but somehow I think I messed up ... https://0bin.net/paste/tTCAKWs0mqAxUekp#m87EWSaEM9hSQ7hE8u2WOOIVYzxy1Jt1Len94qwBWX9

Comment: You've doubled the size in matches instead of halving: if len(seq) == 32: should be 8 and 33 should be 9. I've updated my code to use a single size N.

Comment: Perfect! P.S I actually figured it out in between playing with it more. Thanks!!!!

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. Out of curiosity, how long does this code take to run?

Comment: With 512kB firmware `2,81s user 0,00s system 99% cpu 2,814 total`. BTW Can you also maybe help me with creating a permutation of 32bit where each nibble can be from 1-15. Can repeat themselves. I.e would like to have a list [1-15,1-15,1-15,1-15,1-15,1-15,1-15,1-15] i.e [2,1,4,6,7,11,10,13]. Will this be computeable feasible to calculate and run a quick function through via each value? How many items would the list contain? I can also open a new question, if you would like. You can also contact me via email, let me know, I can share it with you.

Comment: Nahhh... I just have to change my set for this 1-15. Will crunch on it

Comment: Using `itertools` permutations

Comment: @android_dev I'd recommend asking a separate question for the 32 bit case. It shouldn't be too hard with the code I posted. You just need to fiddle with the sizes and the matching algorithm a bit. Please avoid using itertools.permutations for this if you can. It's extremely expensive and implies that you're doing something backwards.

Comment: If you have time and want to take a look, I opened a question for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54197962/fastest-possible-generation-of-permutation-with-defined-element-values-in-python Maybe you can share some knowledge and input on this

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you are trying to search for but...

Each permutation of `(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)` will be a seven item tuple similar to this

```
t = (7, 6, 4, 1, 3, 5, 0, 2)
```

You can make two-item strings like this

```
>>> a = [''.join(map(str,thing)) for thing in zip(t,t[1:])]
>>> a
['76', '64', '41', '13', '35', '50', '02']
```

Then make integers of the strings and feed it to `bytes`

```
>>> b = bytes(map(int,a))
>>> b
b'L@)\r#2\x02'
```

Then search for it

```
>>> b in s
????
```

If it doesn't find it it's not there.

---

Here is a ten character bytes object (similar to your file)

```
>>> b = b'\xcbl\x7f|_k\x00\x9f\xa2\xcc'
```

It just happens to be:

```
>>> bytes([203, 108, 127, 124, 95, 107, 0, 159, 162, 204])
```

Search for *3-character* (or 3-integer) sequences

```
>>> bytes([127,94,107]) in b
False
>>> bytes([127,95,107]) in b
False
>>> bytes([124,95,107]) in b
True
>>>
```

---

When I thing of binary files, I really think integers not characters.